# Why does Java use a static heap rather than allow an arbitrary amount of memory?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, heap-memory, vm-implementation

In Java the virtual machine pre-allocates a memory heap which cannot be expanded at runtime. The developer can increase the size of the  heap with the -Xmx switch when the VM loads, but there is no way to increase the maximum size of the heap at runtime. Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reason per the JVM specification why the heap size must be specified ahead of time except that it was the choice of the implementors. The specification states: "A Java Virtual Machine implementation may provide the programmer or the user control over the initial size of the heap, as well as, if the heap can be dynamically expanded or contracted, control over the maximum and minimum heap size."

The other answers here are just wrong: "The heap may be of a fixed size or may be expanded as required by the computation and may be contracted if a larger heap becomes unnecessary."

Source: The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition. Section 2.5.3, "Heap." That's page 13 in the printed edition.

Answer (score 8):

Fragmentation is a massive problem in memory allocation, as is memory starvation.  It's a lot simpler, and less error-prone if you can allocate and reserve the memory you need, especially in a server environment.  By pre-allocating memory, you also have a higher probability of having most of your memory in continuously allocation (not guaranteed, thank you @mttdbrd) which could be faster to access.

Going back to when Java first started out, installations with more than 1GB of RAM were pretty much unheard of, instead, we had to work with machines that had as little as 256mb of RAM, sometimes even less! Couple that with how slow RAM was, and it made much more sense to be able to read and write to hopefully contiguously allocated blocks.  You are also not constantly hammering the OS to give you more RAM and then releasing it again, freeing up (back then) precious CPU cycles.

In that environment, it's very easy to run out of memory suddenly, so it made a lot of sense to be able to allocate what you MIGHT need and make sure you would have it when the time comes.

These days, I guess with RAM being so much more accessible, it makes a lot less sense, although, when I look at my servers and how memory is allocated, I love the fact that all my Java applications have nice, mostly contiguously allocated blocks of memory when compared to some of the other applications that are all over the place.

That is also why you can't up the heap at runtime, there's no way to guarantee that you will have a contiguous allocation any more.

Comment: I don't see why this is a rationale for not allowing the developer to expand the heap at runtime as long as a big enough section of memory is available.

Comment: The JVM spec is very clear that memory in the heap does *not* need to be contiguous. You may want it to be, but there's not even any guarantee that memory is contiguous on JVM startup. See the JVM spec, 2.5.3.

Comment: @TylerDurden Memory will be available but not contiguous,hence performance will be affected

Comment: @mttdbrd - That is of course true, my answer is too vague on that point, I will amend it right away. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: "there's no way to guarantee that you will have a contiguous allocation any more"--I don't see why thats true. If I have 300M heap and want to expand to 600M, I just allocate 600M, copy the 300M to the beginning of the new 600M, free the old 300M, then the 600M is my new expanded heap. I don't understand why doing this  is not supported.

Comment: @TylerDurden - I understand, but that assumes there's an additional 600M available, making your total allocation 900M at that point. Given that most servers run Gigabytes, not Megabytes, I guess the implementers felt this overhead is too massive.  Maybe that's why I just use Java and didn't help design it :)

Comment: @Ewald I don't see why the VM implementers "feelings" matter at all here. Regardless of the  capabilities of the machine, nothing that I can prevents them from offering an System.ExpandHeap() and returning failure if there is not enough memory. The  question is why this method does not exist? Right now the answer seems to be: "all existing implementers of Java VMs are too stupid to realize they can allow the heap to be expanded". Somehow I doubt this is the explanation. There must be some reason nobody here has determined yet.

Comment: @TylerDurden - Just like you feel that there's a different way of doing things, I reckon the implementers had reasons for their decisions. That being said, nothing prevents you from modifying the OpenJDK and becoming world famous as the man who solved all Java memory issues.  Seriously though, I agree with you, there are other ways to do this, I think the predictability, as pointed out by Marboni, could have been a reason. Often, in hindsight, we regret some of our design decisions, this might just be one of those as well.

Comment: @Ewald I think something deeper must be at work. As far as I know, all VMs enforce a static heap. If it was just a design decision you would think some VMs, especially the commercial, high-performance VMs, would add the extra functionality.

Answer (score 1):

When your code starts to work, JVM is already created and configured. Besides, this limitation guarantees that program will not take all available system resources, breaking normal functioning of other applications on a server regardless how bad its code is. ;)

Comment: The specification makes no bones about it: the heap *may* be dynamically sized. This answer is just incorrect.

Comment: @mttdbrd, heap may be dynamically sized, sure, but not maximum heap size. Question was about maximum heap size, as I understand.

Comment: No. The spec says that it may be dynamically expanded. There is no restriction on heap size in the specification. See my answer: "heap *may be* of a fixed size or may be expanded as required....". The fixed heap size is an implementation detail of Sun's (Oracle's) JVM and NOT a requirement imposed by the specification. Basically it's a implementation detail like Microsoft word using a ribbon instead of a menu bar. The "reason" they did that is unavailable to us. The question OP asked is *Why?* See the question above.

Comment: @mttdbrd, he asks: "... there is no way to increase the maximum size of the heap at runtime. Why is this?" So it's about maximum size, isn't it? In your quote, "The heap may be of a fixed size or may be expanded as required by the computation and may be contracted if a larger heap becomes unnecessary" author tells about dynamical change of heap size. And it's implemented in JVM - memory changes dynamically, but these changes are bounded by minimum and maximum limit that can't be changed dynamically. So it's not an answer. In any case, lets try to provide better answer, not searching for worse.